# Get request method name in axios response interceptor

Tags: axios

I am using axios response interceptor and wish to get request method name (GET/POST/PATCH etc) whenever there is an error in HTTP api.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(error => {
    let method = ''; // How to get which request method was used?
    if (method == 'GET') {
        // do something
    } else if (method == 'POST') {
        // do something else
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
});
```

Any idea how to get the request method name inside this callback?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there actually you set everything right.

If you tried to console **error** object you should see **response** object, which can be undefined (important)

So basically all you have to do is to check if that object has **error.response.headers**